# Angular 2 + Universal AoT internationalization

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular2-aot, angular-universal

I'm currently struggling with i18n support in our Angular 2 + Universal (server-side rendering) project. I would like to have different bundle files for each language (e.g /server/bundle_EN.js and /server/bundle_DE.js).

It does work with client side rendering but I have no clue how to do the same with server side rendering. Because the node server is started once and then it needs to use different template files (depending on the current client language).

Is it possible to pre-compile the project with AoT and seperate language folders and use them on the server?

Thanks!

Comment: Your json files have nothing to do with AOT (AOT compiles your HTML templates into functions)

Comment: I have in my html component templates translations strings like {{translate 'KEY' 'DEFAULT_VALUE'}} and those should be replaced at compile time with the corresponding translation. Therefore I need seperate folders for each language.

The client is able to use the correct folder because I just use different index.html files and include the language specific folder. But for server-side rendering, how can the server switch between languages (server is started with "node server/index.js")